# Conditions on has_many through

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have three classes
`TeamMember`, `Service` and `ServiceTeamMember`

I have

```
class Service
  has_many :service_team_members
  has_many :team_members, through: :service_team_members
end

class ServiceTeamMember
  belongs_to :service
  belongs_to :team_member
end

class TeamMember
  has_many :service_team_members
  has_many :services, through: :service_team_members
end
```

Now in a certain area of my site I want to eager load departments, where a department is a top level service, I'm using ancestry so all you need to know is a department is a service with `ancestry` of `NULL`

So I need an actual association so I can eager load it rather than a scope.

I've tried adding it as such

```
has_many :departments, -> { where(ancestry: nil) }, through: :service_team_members, source: :service
```

But I get the following error

```
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'services.ancestry' in 'where clause': SELECT `service_team_members`.* FROM `service_team_members`  WHERE `services`.`ancestry` IS NULL AND `service_team_members`.`team_member_id` IN (28, 32)
```

So rails is applying my condition to the join table rather than the table I want.  How can I get around this, I assume it's a simple solution and I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Just change `source: :service` by `source: :team_member`

Comment: I thought source is used to show what you're trying to get if rails can't get it from the name of the assocation so for instance I'm calling it `departments` but what I actually want is a `Service`.